# Python writing to a file using data from a function

Tags: python

I have a strange problem on writing to a file using Python. Here is the code:

```
t = func()
print t
f = open('data_t.dat', 'w')
for i in t:
    f.write('%d\n' % (i))
f.close()
```

I did not catch exceptions from the function, but the value of 't' can be printed out as follows:

```
[51535, 96382, 95788, 95293, 94996, 95491, 95392, 96085]
```

But the file cannot be generated. There is no file called "data_t.dat" after running the code. However, if I use the data directly like this, this file can be generated:

```
t = [51535, 96382, 95788, 95293, 94996, 95491, 95392, 96085]
f = open('data_t.dat', 'w')
for i in t:
    f.write('%d\n' % (i))
f.close()
```

I tried it in another way. In this case, the file cannot be generated either:

```
t = func()
t = [51535, 96382, 95788, 95293, 94996, 95491, 95392, 96085]
f = open('data_t.dat', 'w')
for i in t:
    f.write('%d\n' % (i))
f.close()
```

I do not understand what the problem is. Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks!

Follow-up: As pointed out by Adam Smith, the directory has been changed in func(). This is why it happens. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What does "the file cannot be generated" mean? Do you get an exception? Is the file created, but empty?

Comment: Are you sure your code doesn't get any exceptions and leaves in `func()`? In your first example, does it print out `t`?

Comment: By "the file cannot be generated", I mean the file "data_t.dat" is not there. After running the code, no file is written.

Comment: 99% sure @Lafexlos is correct and `func` is throwing an exception which halts code execution

Comment: What, exactly, does `func()` return?  It looks like a list of integers, but is it really something else under the hood?

Comment: @JohnGordon even if it were, the last example in the question would still work.

Comment: In the first code example, does t get printed?

Comment: Does this even make sense? You assign `t` to the return of `func()` and then you overwrite it in the next step

Comment: @LPK in this case it's actually very useful diagnostically because it tells us where the error happened. Everywhere past the `t = func()` we have known working code, so the error MUST be in `func`.

Comment: @LPK Actually it makes a lot of sense -- it shows us the problem is almost certainly within `func()`.

Comment: `t = func()` results in a NameError because 'func' is not defined.

Comment: @Lafexlos I did not catch exceptions, but it did print out the result. This is why it confuses me.

Comment: Is it possible that `func` is doing something *weird*? Like renaming the global `open` or doing `os.chdir` or etc? It could be that `func` is modifying a global state that's necessary to write the file.

Comment: @AdamSmith @JohnGordon  but why does he set `t` equal to funcs value? If the error is inside of func the program would crash anyway. It confuses me that he wants to catch something from func but then decides to overwrite what he got back

Comment: @Lafexlos thinking maybe `func` reads a file from somewhere else and does `os.chdir(ROOT_OF_OTHER_FILE); f = open(OTHER_FILE)`.

Comment: @user1794396 I think you should include `func` in your question. Because `func()` is the cause of problem.

Comment: @LPK he said the middle code block does work successfully, therefore it is very significant that a seemingly-useless operation like calling a function and throwing away the results causes a later write to fail.

Comment: @Adam Smith Yes, you are right. os.chdir is used.

Answer (score 3):

I'm reasonably certain that `func` has code like the following:

```
def func():
    os.chdir("somewhere else")
    f = open("somefile.txt")
    # generate data from somefile.txt
    f.close()
    return some_data
```

`os.chdir` changes your global state, so the new relative path has `"somewhere else"` as a root, not the directory you're running the script in. The easy fix is to instead do:

```
def func():
    f = open("full/qualified/path/to/somefile.txt")
    ...
```

Comment: And the "Psychic of the Day" award goes to...

Comment: @TimPietzcker oh it's early yet....

Comment: Yeah, it is exactly the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The first reason for this problem is that code after 
   `t = func()`
is not reached,because something interrupted it from completing. As I don't see func() body I can't tell the reason why it fails

Comment: the code actually *is* reached, though that was my first conclusion as well. See my answer for the (somewhat precognizant) solution.